Nondimensionalization approach for a coupled ODE (can I set to 1 a coefficient with two characteristic values?)
I'm trying to nondimensionalize the following ODE:
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\mu_1 \frac{1}{r} \frac{\mathrm{~d}}{\mathrm{~d} r}\left(r \frac{\mathrm{~d} u_1}{\mathrm{~d} r}\right)=P_1, & r \in[\alpha, R], \\
\mu_2 \frac{1}{r} \frac{\mathrm{~d}}{\mathrm{~d} r}\left(r \frac{\mathrm{~d} u_2}{\mathrm{~d} r}\right)=P_2, & r \in[0, \alpha],
\end{array}
$$
Where $u_i = f(r)$.
I'm trying to do the following traditional approach:
$$
\bar{u_i} = \frac{u_i}{U_i}, \bar{r}=\frac{r}{R}
$$
And after inserting these I get:
$$
\frac{1}{\bar{r}}\frac{\mathrm{~d}\bar{u_i}}{\mathrm{~d}{\bar{r}}} + \frac{\mathrm{~d}^2\bar{u_i}}{\mathrm{~d}\bar{r}^2}=P_i\frac{R^2}{\mu_iU_i}
$$
My question is can I set:
$$
\frac{R^2}{\mu_i U_i} = 1
$$
Without losing generality? I'm not sure if I'm constraining the possible solutions by setting these values to 1.
If so, is there any other approach to nondimensionalize these Stokes equations?

Performing a scaling transformation $\overline{u}_i=u_i/U_i$ with $U_i=P_i/\mu_i$ is sufficient to transform the right-hand side into the constant unity (assuming $P_i,\mu_i$ are constants). It is not necessary to rescale the independent variable. There is no loss of generality involved, for a scaling transformation applied to $u_i$ amounts physically to a change in the units of $u_i$.

You can transform the right side of $\dfrac{1}{r} \dfrac{du}{dr} + \dfrac{d^2 u}{dr^2} = c$ to  whatever nonzero constant you want by scaling: if $v = k u$,
$\dfrac{1}{r} \dfrac{dv}{dr} + \dfrac{d^2 u}{dr^2} = k c$.

thank you. Can you please expand on if that means I can set $R²/(\mu_i U_i) = 1$? Or I should just name it as a new constant that is nonzero?

You can make $R^2/(\mu_i U_i) = 1$ by taking $U_i = R^2/\mu_i$.
